# Team Foundation Server Express 2013 Get Latest not download to local

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I created window user group and grant all permission for this group in "Team Project Collections".  And when I used VS 2013 to connect to TFS server try to get latest file.

Steps

1. Connect to team project.
2. From the "Connect to Team Foundation Server" dialog, i can only see my Team Project collection in left panel but can't see the team project on the right panel.
3. then Proceed in Source Explorer, i can see my team project, try get latest version by click "Get Latest", it's show all files up to date, but when i check from local directory nothing is downloaded.

Is anything i did wrong? Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the "Connect to Team Foundation Server" dialog, i can only see my
>   Team Project collection in left panel but can't see the team project
>   on the right panel.

At this point you should be able to see the projects that you have access to under the TPC's that you have access to. Ensure at minumum you are in the contributors group for each PROJECT that you require access to

I wouldn't progress until you can see projects at this point.

Comment: So what is the right thing need to do at this point? Permission? Where to set, as i set all of them in team project collections

Comment: Have a look at the project level permissions and ensure your windows group is at minimum in the projects Contributors group.

Comment: OK, now i know there is another place to set permission, http://localhost:8080/tfs/xx/xxWeb/xxWeb%20Team/_admin/_security#_a=memberOf,  Thanks. now i can get all my files.